# Angular2 not updating component from SignalR handler when mouse is not in browser document

Tags: angular, signalr

So I have an app I have been developing in Angular2. One of the things it does it receive events from SignalR and update the data in the browser.

This has been working perfectly when I was running under a development scenario with the Angular starter kit.

Now I am using angular-cli to bundle the application, and it still partially works, but something seems to have broken. If the mouse is not inside of the document window in the browser when the SignalR event is received, the DOM updates don't happen. Even if the mouse is in the address bar of the browser, or over the tabs, it still doesn't update. I can see the logs in the console window showing that the event is received and the data is updated, but the view is not updated.

I'm assuming there's some kind of performance thing going on there, but I think for my case the performance was fine the way it was when using SystemJS, except for the whole downloading 200 js files thing :)

Is there something I need to do to trigger an update from a SignalR event, or something I can do to get the same behavior I was getting before, where the view would be updated automatically, even if I had focus in another app?

**Update:** I found that if I run the code inside of the SignalR handler in a `NgZone.run` block, that it works. That might be good enough, but it would be better if I could get it to work the way it did in the original development environment.

Comment: Hi @Gerald! 
Can u show a code block which triggering update from a SignalR event?

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same issue. I am guessing either Angular 2 didn't monkey patch WebSocket or signalR is using some non-standard API.

As it did for @Gerald, NgZone.run worked for me too.

@Igor Lizunov, Here is how to use NgZone.run()

import ZgZone

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

Inject into constructor

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone)
```

Run ZgZone run in signalR handler

```
hub.on("signalr-event-name", data => {
    /*do something with the data*/
    this.zone.run(() => { });
});
```

Comment: You're saving me after 6 years, man. Thank you from heart